# Puppets "concat::fragment" in Ansible / Create file with defined order

Tags: ansible, puppet

I'm currently tasked with translating our pre-existing Puppet scripts to Ansible.

So far work has been going slow but steady. Now I've come across Puppets "concat::fragment", which (if I don't completely misunderstand) has the "order" parameter that creates files in the given order and if one given order appears multiple times it is added in order of appearance.

E.g.

```
concat::fragment: order   => '10'
concat::fragment: order   => '0-b'
concat::fragment: order   => '5'
concat::fragment: order   => '0-a'
```

would be added in this order:

```
concat::fragment: order   => '0-b'
concat::fragment: order   => '0-a'
concat::fragment: order   => '5'
concat::fragment: order   => '10'
```

If my assumption is not wrong, then I have no idea, how to do this in Ansible.

In short my question would be if this is possible or if I misunderstand the way puppet does it.

I tried to concoct something with regex, but that falls apart quite fast.
I though about perhaps creating temporary files that are named like "<path>_<order>.tmp" and then loop over them somehow, but I'm not sure if all servers would be able to handle it from a space perspective.

Comment: You have your work cut out for you, I think.  Note well that in principle, the `Concat::Fragment`s contributing to a given `Concat::File` can be distributed across the entire manifest set.  Concat is very powerful, very flexible, ... and very alien to the Ansible way of doing things.  I don't think you'll easily perform a direct translation.  You'll probably need to do a higher-level, broader-scoped adaptation that approaches the larger issue differently.

Comment: "and very alien to the Ansible way of doing things"
That's what I thought and feared. This is sadly one of the first big roadblocks to this endeavor.